# Swipe between different screens (views) using storyboards

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

In my project, I'm using the storyboard with 2 tabs. What I want to create is in the first tab, when you swipe left, another layout with text will show and when you swipe left again, another layout shows with other information (so lets say I want 10 different layout templates but I need to be able to change the text from the layout templates.
So this is my storyboard:

[image: http://i52.tinypic.com/28at3yh.png]

And in the "First View" I need to be able to swipe left and show a layout with text, swipe left again and show (for example) the same layout with another text, swipe left again show another layout with text and so on. So in total there are 10 layout templates where I need to be able to change the text in code.

So basically what I'm aiming for is the same as the start window on the iPhone/iPad where you can swipe between the screens where the app icons are on. How can I accomplish this with the same animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is called `UIPageControl`. The class reference can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and a really good tutorial can be found [here](http://www.wannabegeek.com/?p=168).

If you want a more fancy `UIPageControl` with more customizable options I suggest you try out any of [these](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=uiPagecontrol). (The `SMPageControl` is one of my own personal favorites)

**EDIT due to comments:**

[Here](https://github.com/wannabegeek/PageViewController) is a link to the project from the tutorial above.

In `CustomPagerViewController` he calls

```
[self addChildViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View1"]];
```

which gives the equivalent result as

```
UIViewController *aViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View1"];
[self addChildViewController:aViewController];
```

Now, if you want to add several ViewControllers you could do a loop as follows

```
for(int i = 0; i<yourNumberOfViewControllers; i++) {
    YourViewControllerClass *aViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourIdentifier"];
    [aViewController setSomeProperty:someValue];
    [self addChildViewController:aViewController];
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I saw that tutorial, but the problem is he made 3 screens in the storyboard, but I need to have for example 10 layouts, and reuse them with other content on it so that I can scroll maybe 50 times...

Comment: So the problem is that I cannot make all the screens in the storyboard, because I parse an XML, and dependent on that XML I need to make the views, and I don't know how much maybe there are 5, maybe 10...

Comment: What is the YourViewControllerClass? Do you mean FirstViewController ? I'm using 2 view controllers as you can see in my image, FirstViewController class that is linked with the first view, and SecondViewController that is linked with the second one. And do I need to put this code in the FirstViewController then? I'm a little confused

Comment: @nonuma Sorry if I didn't explain it very well. If you download the sample project from my link above you will see that it contains a class called CustomPagerViewController. In that class you will see how the author of the tutorial instanciates new UIViewControllers (or pages in this case) by adding childViewControllers. In the for - loop I demonstrate an other way of freely adding childViewControllers based on a specific number (that you very well can get from an XML-file).

Comment: @nonuma So the 'YourViewControllerClass' would be the class of the UIViewController that you want to add several 'pages' of.

Comment: All right, it's late now so I will test this out tomorrow, thanks!
Edit: So I need to make another view controller class actually?

Comment: @nonuma Sleep on it! ;) I think you will get it while trying it out. But basically the 'ViewControllers' that you add as children to the 'CustomPagerViewController' can be subclassed UIViewControllers doing whatever you want them to do.

Comment: I now started from that tutorial project, there are 3 views created in the storyboard, is it possible to reuse those, but with other text and objects on it? So lets say I can scroll between 40 screens but only use those 3 templates, but with a different text on it?

Comment: Ok, but then I just create another view that has the same data on it, but I want to change the data on it, so instead of "View 1" like in the tutorial I want to change it with "Some other text" or add a button on it

Comment: I'll explain it a little more: http://i49.tinypic.com/f3cs2b.png look at this picture. There are 3 views with the same "layout" (its just the background now) and I want to reuse those, instead of making them all in the storyboard, because then I would have 50 views in the storyboard and it also depends on my XML that I parse (maybe there are 3 with the same layout, maybe 10)